# Will streaming .wav audio with Xamarin make any compression?

Tags: audio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking into streaming .wav files from a server. I'm wondering if the devices will stream/play the music without any compression applied. I need to ensure that no compression is made. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not seeing here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html anything about compression, i think it doesn't compress the audio